# AndroidStudio,doe not show "hello world"

Tags: android-studio

i have just downloaded androio studio and i have 2 issues.At first it does now show the "hello world" text and when i try to put a button it shows me this(**this view is not constraint.it has  designtime positions,so it will jump to (0,0) at runtime unless you add the constraints)**

Anyone could help?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot? Screenshot of device? Did you install the Android Platform Tools correctly?

Comment: this is a good solution i found:http://hintslibrary.blogspot.com/2012/05/warning-hardcoded-string-str-should-use.html

but it still does not shown in design

Answer (score 0):

Convert Constraint Layout to Relative/Linear Layout for beginners its best to start with Relative/Linear Layout

Copy this and replace with your old code in activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: hardcoded string "button",should use @string button resource...any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: go to strings.xml and add your string, 

<string name="buttonname">YourTextHere</string>

and to your 
<Button
android:text="@string/buttonname"

Comment: http://hintslibrary.blogspot.com/2012/05/warning-hardcoded-string-str-should-use.html

Comment: if your problem is resolved accept answer so it might help others when they look for